# Plot an area under a curve in R using polygon

Tags: r, polygon

Hi I am trying to color under the line above 25 on the x axis and it either not showing anything or giving me error, x and y are different length any help would be great Thanks Rob

[image]

Comment: It's easier to help you if you include a simple [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) with sample input and desired output that can be used to test and verify possible solutions. Pictures of code aren't helpful; we don't want to have to retype that.

Answer (score 2):

You need to start with some plot. `polygon` just adds to an existing plot. 
Also, You need to include a few extra points to get the area under the curve, not over.

```
x2 = c(x, 40, 25)
y2 = c(y, 0, 0)
plot(x,y, type="n")
polygon(x2,y2, col="yellow")
```

[image: Polygon]

Answer (score 2):

Here is another way.

```
x <- 25:40
y <- dpois(x, 23.83)
plot(x, y, type = "n")
polygon(c(x, rev(x)), c(y, rep(0, length(y))), col = "yellow")
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you, @Rui Barradas, 4 years on this is very helpful!